# Setting default text in WYMEDITOR

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, wymeditor

I've got a question about using WYMEditor in ASP.NET MVC 3 with jQuery. I'd like to set default text in WYMEditor on my web page. If I'm doing in that way :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function() {
   jQuery(".wymeditor").wymeditor( { html : '<strong>some text</strong>'});
 });
```

There is no problem, and wymeditor shows well-formated text, but is I try it in that way :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function() {
   jQuery(".wymeditor").wymeditor( { html : '@ViewBag.HtmlText'});

 });
```

(HtmlText is variable where I keep : `<strong>some text</strong>`) the WymEditor shows me not formated text `<strong>some text</strong>`. I tried HtmlEncoding and etc, but it stil isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function() {
        var html = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.HtmlText));
        jQuery('.wymeditor').wymeditor({ html: html });
    });
</script>
```

And please get rid of this `ViewBag` as everytime I see it I get sick. Use view models and strongly typed views.

Comment: I've got different view model for it, but this is only quick example. Thx a lot.

Comment: @jacbar, in this case maybe you could consider [marking this as answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), unless of course you have some issues with it and it wasn't helpful to you.

Comment: I tried to vote up, but without 15 points of reputation I can't